# How to handle App on click of VoIp notification?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, voip, uilocalnotification

In My app, We are using VoIp Push Notification and It works fine. We have handled all code on `pushRegistry:didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload` and firing local notification in this method.

We need to find whether the app is launched from notification (on tap of notification in notification screen) to restrict firing local notificaiton. We tried to get `launchOptions` from `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method but It seems`pushRegistry:didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload` called before `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and sometimes `launchOptions` is`null`, Any Solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Whole voip integration notes and code you can refer here https://github.com/hasyapanchasara/PushKit_SilentPushNotification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `VoIp Push Notification` allways wake up and launch your application, it doesn't create a local notification by it's own. If a user tap on local notification you have created and fired -> then the app is launched from local notification you already created and fired.

So it's working as expected.